# python generate 2 numbers with max multiply result

Tags: python, random

I try generate 2 numbers with max multiply result 12.

I try:

```
height = random.randint(1, 12)
width = random.randint(1, 12//height)
```

The problem is that the probability of height being greater than width is higher.

How can I generate the height and width independently of each other?

Comment: The problem is that `x` is not defined.

Comment: you are dividing by `height`?

Comment: You could pick both numbers in the 1...12 range, and try again if the product is over 12 - but that's going to take a long time on average.  Or you can use your current code, and then randomly (50% chance) swap the two numbers - that should give them equal statistical properties.

Comment: How about generating a random *area* and height and then calculate the width by dividing those two?

Comment: Can you clarify what your criteria on the two numbers are? By construction of requiring a max multiply, they *cannot* be independent.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: I think that you wanted the product to be less than 12 (not necessarily 12), but I'm still going to let this answer remain here for now.

If my answer doesn't help you, you could comment your problem in more detail and with more context of what you're trying to get.

I think you are trying to generate two random numbers, with their product 12.

I can think of multiple ways to achieve this, and this is one of them:

```
from random import choice # import choice

num = 12 # this number will control the product

factorChoice = choice([i for i in range(1,num+1) if num%i==0]) # selects a random factor of num

height = factorChoice # this is the height

width = 12//factorChoice # this is the width

print(f'Height: {height}\nWidth: {width}') # printing results
```

This is pretty inefficient, and looks even weirder, but hey— it works.